# Hi. try running yarn install. I do not know what is this error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg

I am running `yarn install`. I do not know what this error is.

```
[DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and 
usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or 
Buffer.from() methods instead.
```

Comment: It's not an error. It's just a _warning_.

Comment: it does not allow me to install dependencies.  Thank you

Comment: Updating yarn might help. They should have fixed that by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yarn uses deprecated new Buffer().

Upgrading the node/yarn version or `yarn global add yarn` might be able to solve. Can you please try and confirm!!

Answer (score 1):

You use new version [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), [yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn) use some code look like `new Buffer()`(`Buffer() is deprecated`).
With last version `yarn` have not fix it yet, you just wait.

This is warning, you can use `yarn`.